# MS Test V2 - ClassInitialize behavior when fail

Tags: c#, mstest

I use VS2019 with MS Test V2 framework and test adapter. 
I am a bit unsure about the intended behavior of ClassInitialize.

When I run a group of tests from a test class:

- In MS Test V1.3 if ClassInitialize failed, all tests were reported as failed.
- In MS Test V2 it seems that only the first test is reported as failed, all other are reported as passed.

When I run the tests independently (one at a time) each test is reported as failed.
So I thought this might be an issue of parallel execution, but even after disabling parallel execution the behavior is the same in MS Test v2.

Is it intended that the ClassInitialize fail does not fail all tests?

Comment: Please, share example of your tests

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Christian was so kind to publish his code example, which covers my scenario completely.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I can repro this behavior with a .NET Core UnitTestProject using MSTest 2.0.0.

Here is the test class' code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInit(TestContext tc)
        {
            throw new Exception("DIE IN INITIALIZE");
        }

        [TestMethod] public void TestMethod1() { }
        [TestMethod] public void TestMethod2() { }
        [TestMethod] public void TestMethod3() { }
    }
}
```

And indeed if you look at the results in TestExplorer, you can see that only `TestMethod1` is marked as Failed, while `TestMethod2` and `TestMethod3` are marked as `Successful`.

Same result from the console.

```
❯ dotnet test
Test run for C:\source\stuff\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\UnitTestProject2.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
  X TestMethod1
  Error Message:
   Class Initialization method UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.ClassInit threw exception. System.Exception: System.Exception: DIE IN INITIALIZE.
  Stack Trace:
     at UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.ClassInit(TestContext tc) in C:\source\stuff\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject2\UnitTest1.cs:line 12


Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 3
     Passed: 2
     Failed: 1
 Total time: 0,8928 Seconds
```

Interestingly, if you add some `Console.WriteLine` statements to the test methods, you can see, that indeed they are really executed. So it doesn't seem to be a mishap in the output only.

**Update** Not sure if this is to be expected, but I submitted an issue for it https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/672.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and code example Christian, this fully covers my scenario